# MySQL procedure to convert formula to list of numbers

Tags: sql, mysql, string, parsing, concatenation

I have a list of alphanumeric strings that includes two special characters `+` and `-`. The input, as shown below, represents part numbers for our company's products. I would like to extract the individual components as an output. There are about 45,000 products, and the data below is a sample of the part numbers. How can I parse this string to distinguish between `+` and `-` and provide the correct output?

[image]

I am unsure how to distinguish between range indicated by `-` and addition indicated by `+`.

Comment: What output must be provided for the next source data: `1-2-3`, `3-1`, `1-3-2`, `1+1+1`. Do not tell "such values are impossible" (if trouble can happen, it happens) - or show the constraint which provides the absence of such values.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to call it inside SELECT  statements use `CREATE FUNCTION`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION RangeFormulaToList(input_string VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE output_list TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE current_part VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE range_start INT;
    DECLARE range_end INT;
    DECLARE range_separator_pos INT;
    DECLARE plus_separator_pos INT;
    DECLARE current_number INT;
    DECLARE delimiter_pos INT;

    -- Replace '+' with ','
    SET input_string = REPLACE(input_string, '+', ',');

    -- Add a comma at the end to ensure the last number is processed
    SET input_string = CONCAT(input_string, ',');

    -- Process each part of the input string
    WHILE LENGTH(input_string) > 0 DO
        -- Find the position of the next comma delimiter
        SET delimiter_pos = INSTR(input_string, ',');
        -- Extract the current part
        SET current_part = TRIM(SUBSTRING(input_string, 1, delimiter_pos - 1));
        -- Remove the processed part from the input string
        SET input_string = SUBSTRING(input_string, delimiter_pos + 1);

        -- Find the position of the range separator '-'
        SET range_separator_pos = INSTR(current_part, '-');
        IF range_separator_pos > 0 THEN
            -- If a range separator is found
            SET range_start = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(current_part, '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED);
            SET range_end = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(current_part, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED);

            -- Append the range to the output list
            WHILE range_start <= range_end DO
                SET output_list = CONCAT(output_list, IF(output_list = '', '', ','), range_start);
                SET range_start = range_start + 1;
            END WHILE;
        ELSE
            -- If no range separator is found, it's a single number
            SET current_number = CAST(current_part AS UNSIGNED);
            SET output_list = CONCAT(output_list, IF(output_list = '', '', ','), current_number);
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN (output_list);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

So that You'll be able to do:

```
SELECT 
  formula,
  RangeFormulaToList(formula) as list
FROM formulas;
```

[image: sample execution]

Gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/num8er/89d41bda87a0d8ccb6b254d822f9f230)

Comment: i try on mysql workbench but it doesn't work! If you run CALL ConvertToList('1-3+5') the output is 1,3,5, but the expected result shoud be 1,2,3,5

Comment: @MattiaTrombon fixing, wait a bit

Comment: @MattiaTrombon  fixed, check please

Comment: @MattiaTrombon even works with this: `CALL ConvertRangesToList('21-30+1-12+20');
`

Comment: it works, great job!

Comment: @MattiaTrombon I've updated my answer with stored function to be able to use with SELECT statements

Answer (score 0):

See example.
Disassemble a string, generate series and reassemble it using two recursive subqueries and grouping back.

```
with recursive splt as( -- parsing formula string to parts
select id,0 lvl,inFormula,outTest
  ,case when regexp_instr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
         cast(regexp_substr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}') as signed) 
   end n1
  ,case when regexp_instr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
         cast(regexp_substr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}') as signed) 
   end n2
  ,case when regexp_instr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
      substr(inFormula,length(regexp_substr(inFormula,'[0-9]{1,}'))+1,100)
   else ''
   end rest
from test
union all
select id,lvl+1 lvl,inFormula,outTest
  ,case when left(rest,1)='-' then n2+1
        when regexp_instr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
     cast(regexp_substr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}') as signed) 
   end n1
  ,case when left(rest,1)='-' then 
          case when regexp_instr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
            cast(regexp_substr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}') as signed)
          end
        when regexp_instr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
          cast(regexp_substr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}') as signed) 
   end n2
  ,case when regexp_instr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}')>0 then
      substr(rest,length(regexp_substr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}'))+2,100)
   else ''
   end rest
from splt
where regexp_instr(rest,'[0-9]{1,}')>0  -- and lvl<5  <- for debug only
)
,series as( -- generate additional rows for diapasons like 4-6
   select id,lvl,0 lvl2,inFormula,outTest,n2 lastN
      ,n1
   from splt
   union all
   select id,lvl,lvl2+1 lvl2,inFormula,outTest,lastN
      ,n1+1
   from series
   where (n1+1)<=lastN
)
-- assembling all back
select id,inFormula,outTest
  ,group_concat(n1 order by n1) newList
from series 
group by id,inFormula,outTest
order by id;
```

Output

| id | inFormula | outTest | newList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-3 | 1,2,3 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 1+3 | 1,3 | 1,3 |
| 3 | 4+7+8 | 4,7,8 | 4,7,8 |
| 4 | 1-3+5-6 | 1,2,3,5,6 | 1,2,3,5,6 |
| 5 | 2+4-6 | 2,4,5,6 | 2,4,5,6 |
| 6 | 2-4+6 | 2,3,4,6 | 2,3,4,6 |
| 7 | 2-4-6 | 2,3,4,5,6 | 2,3,4,5,6 |
| 8 | 23 | 23 | 23 |
| 9 | 19- | 19 | 19 |
| 10 |  |  | null |
| 11 | 27-28-30-31 | 27,28,29,30,31 | 27,28,29,30,31 |
| 12 | 999-1001+10004 | 999,1000,1001,1004 | 999,1000,1001,10004 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BHhgZNqX)

Comment: Good solution. But IMO regexp is slow operation and in inexperienced hands may be harmful with bugs like endless loop, not talking about big table of records too. Another opinioin: would be great if You converted it to stored function. Cause writing so much query code may be limited by mysql configs: `max_allowed_packet`. So it's always beautiful to have simple `SELECT formula, FormulaToList(formula) FROM formulas` than big sql query.

Comment: Case with stored procedure, like your ``RangeFormulaToList``, is a more suitable option for such a task. However, if for some reason it is not possible to use a stored procedure (no rights for DDL) , there are options left to do on the client side or use such a request. I was also just interested in solving the problem in this way.

Comment: ``regexp`` operations on strings are a very well-developed tool in MySQL. Therefore, the performance of such a solution will be quite good. ``max_allowed_packet`` default value =4MB, they are unlikely to be a limitation. ``maxrecursion`` - it's hard to say without knowing the real data.